# Avoid type checking when function dependant on two distinct classes

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to code a game hub of sorts that is basically a collection of board games or games that can be easily played at the command line. (Tic Tac Toe, Connect Four, etc.) The user also has the option of making any of the two players computers. If I were making only Tic Tac Toe this wouldn't be an issue since I could just have "move" implemented in the human and computer subclass of Player and then invoke the correct one polymorphically, but with the addition of other games I'm not sure how to get away from type checking. For instance, if move is a function within player, how else other than through type checking would the function know whether to move according to the rules of Tic Tac Toe or Connect Four?

I was toying with the idea of having a separate move class with different subclasses for each scenario but I'm not sure if that's correct or how to implement it.

This is being written in C++ by the way.

Comment: Making move polymorphic is OK. Then make a game (or several games) an let the game instantiate the move object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all games to inherit from the same `game_base` base class, then you need people who use these games to not "know" which game they are playing.

What do I mean? You asked

> For instance, if move is a function within player, how else other than through type checking would the function know whether to move according to the rules of Tic Tac Toe or Connect Four?

Let me ask you this instead - say you did solve this problem like you described it. Now you want to add a new game (say, checkers). Will you need to change `player` to know how to play checkers?

If so - then your games shouldn't use inheritance (shouldn't all inherit from `game_base`

Why? Because basically you're saying "my `player` class has to have built-in all the possibilities of all the games". If that is the case, why have different games classes?

As a solution I would say something like this:

- How would the human player class if it needs to move according to tic-tac-toe or connect-four? The GAME class should tell it! More than that - assume the player doesn't know the game at all! TELL the player what are the current legal moves!

An example:

```
class game_base{
  // returns the number of players in this game. 
  // Doesn't change during play
  virtual int num_players() = 0;
  // returns the current player - the player whose turn it is now
  virtual int curr_player() = 0;
  // returns a string that describes (or draws) the current
  // game state
  virtual std::string draw_board()const = 0;
  // returns all the possible legal moves the player can 
  // make this turn
  virtual std::vector<std::string> curr_turn_possible_moves()const = 0;
  // Plays the given move. Has to be one of the moves
  // returned by curr_turn_possible_moves()
  virtual void play(std::string move) = 0;
  // returns the player who won the game, or -1 if the 
  // game is still ongoing
  virtual int won() = 0;
};
```

See how you can use this game class in a way that the same `player` class can play all games you'd ever make!

You can even make a "check all option up to N levels deep" computer player that will work with every game!

- About the computer player: You can make a "generic" computer player that tries to go N steps forward to look for a winning strategy (you need to add the option to `virtual game_base *copy()const` the current game state). But in reality you would need a computer player tailored for each game (that only plays that game).

So how do you do that? More importantly - how would you know which computer player to select for each game?

All computer players will inherit from a `computer_player_base` class (that probably has only one function `play` that plays the next move given a game). The trick is - if you now want to add a new computer player for a game (either for a new game, or another possible computer player for an existing game), you need a way to "register" that player. You want something that would look like:

```
std::vector<computer_player_base*> possible_computer_players(const game_base*game);
```

that returns all the possible computer players that know how to play the given game. The easiest way to do that - is to have the computer player class itself tell you if it can play the given game. So it would look something like this:

```
class computer_player_base{
  // return true if this class knows how to play this game
  // implemented using dynamic_cast - something like this:
  // return dynamic_cast<connect_4*>(game) != 0;
  virtual bool can_play(game_base *game) = 0;
  // plays the next turn of the game
  virtual void play(game_base *game) = 0;
};
```

Then have, e.g., a global list of all computer players to choose from

```
std::vector<computer_player_base*> all_computer_players
```

that you will fill with one of each computer player, and a function

```
std::vector<computer_player_base*> possible_computer_players(game_base *game)
{
  std::vector<computer_player_base*> res;
  for (auto p:all_computer_players)
    if (p->can_play(game))
      res.push_back(p);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into implementing that soon. Never really thought of it that way.

Comment: @Keltek Note that's just a basic idea, not a full solution. You'll have many different things to consider. The important part is to think of it like this: you want to be able to add new games (new children of `game_base`) without changing anything else in the program. Same with adding new computer players.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
enum GameType {
TicTacToe,
ConnectFour,
SnakesLadders,
Battleships,
};
```

And then store GameType gt inside the game-playing object you are using. Then do a `switch(gt)` inside each method.